# Error in calling a function defined within a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I've been provided with a code to create a doubly-linked list. A node in the linked list is a struct by the name of *ListItem*. Now within that node is a function that assigns a value to the node. The problem that I'm having is that I can't seem to create a node and use the function to assign the value to it.

Here's the code for the struct "*ListItem*".

```
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
    T value;
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;

    ListItem(T theVal)
    {
        this->value = theVal;
        this->next = NULL;
        this->prev = NULL;
    }
};
```

The corresponding *ListItem* functions in the accompanying .cpp file:

```
template <class T>
ListItem<T>* List<T>::getHead()
{
}

template <class T>
ListItem<T>* List<T>::getTail()
{
}

template <class T>
ListItem<T> *List<T>::searchFor(T item)
{
}
```

Here's what I was attempting to do in my main function.

```
int main()
{
    ListItem<int> a;
    a.ListItem(int 5);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

All I'm trying to do here is create a node and assign a value to it. Following are the errors I'm getting:

=**'a' is not a class or namespace**

=**missing template arguments before '(' token**

=**expected primary expression before 'int'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a `struct` is just the same as a `class`, so what you've done is create a class with the name `ListItem` containing a normal constructor taking a single argument.

You create it like normal:

```
ListItem<int> a(5);
```

You have some other problems as well, like having functions for the class that are not declared in the class (e.g. the `getHead` function). You also can not have the implementation of templated function members in a separate source file, they have to be in the header file together with the class (or struct) definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, first of all. I get your point about the functions not being declared in the class/struct, but I don't get your point about member functions being declared in a separate file. Take getHead, for example. Are you saying the implementation of getHead should be within the class definition?

Comment: @SaadTariq When a templated class is used, it need the _complete_ definition, not only the class but the functions too. Either place the functions inline in the class, or place them separately after the class definition (like you have now, but put the functions in the header file instead of a separate source file).

Answer (score 2):

ListItem is not a function name, but the constructor of the class/structure. The constructor is a special function and cannot be called like that. Your code should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    ListItem<int> a(5);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```